# Enclave field not working, but there is no error

Tags: visual-studio, intel, sgx

I'm trying make simple code call an enclave field and just add 1.

I'm reference this site : https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-with-sgx-sdk-f...

After it finishes, there is no error, but the enclave code is not working.

Here is my project.zip code with Visual Studio 2017    https://drive.google.com/open?id=13trTAamhNWaz2Q2BRDtUFP5qCX8Syyuc

app.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "sgx_urts.h"
#include "Enclave1_u.h"

#define ENCLAVE_FILE _T("Enclave1.signed.dll")

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int i = 0;

    sgx_enclave_id_t eid;
    sgx_status_t ret = SGX_SUCCESS;
    sgx_launch_token_t token = { 0 };
    int updated = 0;

    ret = sgx_create_enclave(ENCLAVE_FILE, SGX_DEBUG_FLAG, &token, &updated, &eid, NULL);
    if (ret != SGX_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("APP error%#x, failed to create enclave. \n", ret);
        return -1;
    }

    int *ptr = &a;
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);

    while (i<5) {
        foo(eid, ptr);
        printf("%d\n", *ptr);       
        Sleep(1000);
        i++;
    }

    if (SGX_SUCCESS != sgx_destroy_enclave(eid))
        return -1;
}
```

Enclave1.edl

enclave {
    from "sgx_tstdc.edl" import *;

```
trusted {
    /* define ECALLs here. */
    public void foo([in, size = 4]int *ptr);
};

untrusted {
    /* define OCALLs here. */

};
```

};

Enclave1.cpp

```
#include "Enclave1_t.h"
#include "sgx_trts.h"
#include <string.h>

void foo(int *ptr)
{   
    if (*ptr == 1) *ptr == 43971;
    *ptr += 1;
}
```

I expected it to print:

> 43971, 43972, 43973, 43974 .....

But the result is:

> 1, 1, 1, .........

What did I miss?

Comment: Try `public void foo([in, size = 8]int *ptr);` in the `.edl` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem.

1. foo needs [out] instad of [in] so Enclave1.edl should

   enclave { from "sgx_tstdc.edl" import *;

   ```
      trusted {
          /* define ECALLs here. */
          public void foo([out, size = 4]int *ptr);
      };

      untrusted {
          /* define OCALLs here. */

      };
   };
   ```
2. project1.signed.dll file is not updated on debug folder. so i try rebuild project and it updated. I'm realized this file is enclave field itself
3. IF state grammar is wrong. it should be `if (*ptr == 1) *ptr = 43971;`